# React Infinite scroll causing browser to crash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using react-infinite-scroll-component library to implement infinite scrolling feature and then I am mapping 10 videos at a time after about 50 videos being mapped my browser is crashing. Is there any way to fix this? I am trying to implement tiktok like feature in my website.

My states

```
const [data, setData] =  useState([]);
const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);
```

This is my map function where I map a video player

```
{data.map((items,i)=>{
            return (
                 <VideoPlayerShorts
                  loop={true}
                  sources={[
                  {
                    src: items.video_details.trim_video_link,
                    type: "application/x-mpegURL",
                  },
                ]}
              />
```

This is my infinite Scroll feature

```
<InfiniteScroll
          dataLength={data.length}
          next={getMoreData}
          hasMore={hasMore}
        > 
</InfiniteScroll>
```

My Function which gets called on Infinite scroll

```
const getMoreData = async () => {

      page = page + 1;
      const body = {
        current_page:page

      const responce = await axios.post("Api Link", body)
    const shorts = await responce.data.data.shots;
    
    shorts.map((items,i)=>{
      setData([...data, items]);
    }) 
    console.log("data.......",data);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors at all? Could you provide the code for the `VideoPlayerShorts` component?

Comment: I don't get any errors Just my chrome tab shows aw snap Something went wrong while displaying this webpage. Error Code SIGILL.

Comment: I debugged it further and found that it is crashing only when my data array is having 61 values and it is happening on Chrome only I tried same on Firefox and it is working fine over there.